# Error when calling ToListAsync() method of Windows Azure Mobile service using mvvmcross in Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, azure-mobile-services

I am building an app with AzureMobile Services in mvvmcross when I call ToListAsync() method for retrieving data from server in Windows Phone 8 it works fine but there is an error in Xamarin.Android. Any one suggest me to resolve the issue.

Here is a full error stack

```
mvx:Warning: 39.64 Exception masked AggregateException: 
12-02 14:06:53.317 I/mono-stdout( 2032): mvx:Warning: 39.64 Exception masked AggregateException: 
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EmployeeDirectoryCross.Core.Models.Employee]].get_Result () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-02 14:06:53.326 I/mono-stdout( 2032):      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EmployeeDirectoryCross.Core.Models.Employee]].get_Result () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-02 14:06:53.335 I/mono-stdout( 2032):   at EmployeeDirectoryCross.Core.ViewModels.EmployeeListViewModel+<>c__DisplayClass2.<SearchEmployees>b__1 () [0x00001] in e:\Study\Xamarin\XamrinSamples\EmployeeDirectoryCross\EmployeeDirectoryCross.Core\ViewModels\EmployeeListViewModel.cs:54 
12-02 14:06:53.335 D/Mono    ( 2032): Unloading image System.dll [0x2b365118].
12-02 14:06:53.335 D/Mono    ( 2032): Image addref System[0x2b354bf8] -> System.dll[0x2a6189d8]: 18
  at EmployeeDirectoryCross.Core.ViewModels.EmployeeListViewModel+<>c__DisplayClass2.<SearchEmployees>b__1 () [0x00001] in e:\Study\Xamarin\XamrinSamples\EmployeeDirectoryCross\EmployeeDirectoryCross.Core\ViewModels\EmployeeListViewModel.cs:54 
12-02 14:06:53.355 I/mono-stdout( 2032):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxMainThreadDispatcher.ExceptionMaskedAction (System.Action action) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxMainThreadDispatcher.ExceptionMaskedAction (System.Action action) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-02 14:06:53.355 I/mono-stdout( 2032): InnerException was MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The server did not provide a response with the expected content.
InnerException was MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The server did not provide a response with the expected content.
      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<SendRequestAsync>d__1c.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-02 14:06:53.355 I/mono-stdout( 2032):      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<SendRequestAsync>d__1c.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
12-02 14:06:53.355 I/mono-stdout( 2032): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-02 14:06:53.365 I/mono-stdout( 2032):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-02 14:06:53.365 I/mono-stdout( 2032):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-02 14:06:53.385 I/mono-stdout( 2032):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<RequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: I use MvvmCross/MobileServiceAzure with Android and WindowsPhone using ToListAsync().  It works fine.  Do you have sample code or demo project?

Comment: "The server did not provide a response with the expected content" suggests that the json response back from the server was empty - https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/blob/98945a95f416f75f9f16736221706e9f0ea877f9/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Http/MobileServiceHttpClient.cs#L539. Some sort of sample code might help debug this